# If a server is headless (CentOS 7) is there a way to make the GPU used as an extra CPU core?

Tags: centos, hardware, linux-networking, centos7, headless

I've got a server with centOS that has no graphical interface. I only connect to it via ssh. As a result, the GPU is probably not used for much. I'd like to make the server use it as an extra CPU core. Is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible in the sense of a "normal" CPU. You could use CUDA or a similar library if supported on your GPU chip, but that is not at all useful for general server tasks.

However, most servers that are not designed for GPU computing have very weak GPUs  and wouldn't offer any real benefit anyway.